# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in atom text editor usind cmd promt

Tags: python

I ran the code and I get the error `'str' object is not callable`

```py
import random, string

def generator():
    letter1 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    letter2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    letter3 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    letter4 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    letter5 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)


letter_input_1 = input('choose a letter..."v"for vowels, "c" for consonants, "l" for any other letter, or pick any letter:')
letter_input_2 = input('choose a letter..."v"for vowels, "c" for consonants, "l" for any other letter, or pick any letter:')
letter_input_3 = input('choose a letter..."v"for vowels, "c" for consonants, "l" for any other letter, or pick any letter:')
letter_input_4 = input('choose a letter..."v"for vowels, "c" for consonants, "l" for any other letter, or pick any letter:')
letter_input_5 = input('choose a letter..."v"for vowels, "c" for consonants, "l" for any other letter, or pick any letter:')

vowels = 'aeiouy'
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
letter = string.ascii_lowercase

def generator():

    if letter_input_1 == "v":
        letter1 = random.choice(vowels)
    elif letter_input_1 == "c":
        letter1 = random.choice(consonants)
    elif letter_input_1 == "l":
        letter1 = random.choice(letter)
    else:
        letter1 = letter_input_1 #allowing user to select a specific letter

if letter_input_2 == "v":
    letter2 = random.choice(vowels)
elif letter_input_2 == "c":
    letter2 = random.choice(consonants)
elif letter_input_2 == "l":
        letter2 = random.choice(letter)
else:
        letter2 = letter_input_2 #allowing user to select a specific letter

if letter_input_3 == "v":
    letter3 = random.choice(vowels)
elif letter_input_3 == "c":
    letter3 = random.choice(consonants)
elif letter_input_3 == "l":
    letter3 = random.choice(letter)
else:
    letter3 = letter_input_3 #allowing user to select a specific letter

if letter_input_4 == "v":
    letter4 = random.choice(vowels)
elif letter_input_4 == "c":
    letter4 = random.choice(consonants)
elif letter_input_4 == "l":
    letter4 = random.choice(letter)
else:
    letter4 = letter_input_4 #allowing user to select a specific letter

if letter_input_5 == "v":
    letter5 = random.choice(vowels)
elif letter_input_5 == "c":
    letter5 = random.choice(consonants)
elif letter_input_5 == "l":
    letter5 = random.choice(letter)
else:
    letter5 = letter_input_5 #allowing user to select a specific letter
name = 'letter1+letter2+letter3+letter4+letter5'
'return'(name )

for babynames in range(20):
    print(generator())
```

it should give random letters based on the variable i entered but instead i get the error

```
File "C:\Users\17348\Desktop\py4e\babynames4.py", line 69, in <module>
    'return'(name )
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: You're calling `'return'(name)`. `'return'` is a string, and you're treating it like a function, thus the error.

Comment: thank you i also had my indenting messed up

Answer (score 0):

The problem on your code is that the indentation is wrong, and things are strings when they shouldn't be.

Particularly this lines:

```
name = 'letter1+letter2+letter3+letter4+letter5'
'return'(name )
```

By indenting them correctly and turn the strings into statements, you get this code, which appear to do what you want:

```
import random, string

letter_input_1 = input('choose a letter..."v"for vowels, "c" for consonants, "l" for any other letter, or pick any letter:')
letter_input_2 = input('choose a letter..."v"for vowels, "c" for consonants, "l" for any other letter, or pick any letter:')
letter_input_3 = input('choose a letter..."v"for vowels, "c" for consonants, "l" for any other letter, or pick any letter:')
letter_input_4 = input('choose a letter..."v"for vowels, "c" for consonants, "l" for any other letter, or pick any letter:')
letter_input_5 = input('choose a letter..."v"for vowels, "c" for consonants, "l" for any other letter, or pick any letter:')

vowels = 'aeiouy'
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
letter = string.ascii_lowercase

def generator():

    if letter_input_1 == "v":
        letter1 = random.choice(vowels)
    elif letter_input_1 == "c":
        letter1 = random.choice(consonants)
    elif letter_input_1 == "l":
        letter1 = random.choice(letter)
    else:
        letter1 = letter_input_1 #allowing user to select a specific letter

    if letter_input_2 == "v":
        letter2 = random.choice(vowels)
    elif letter_input_2 == "c":
        letter2 = random.choice(consonants)
    elif letter_input_2 == "l":
            letter2 = random.choice(letter)
    else:
            letter2 = letter_input_2 #allowing user to select a specific letter

    if letter_input_3 == "v":
        letter3 = random.choice(vowels)
    elif letter_input_3 == "c":
        letter3 = random.choice(consonants)
    elif letter_input_3 == "l":
        letter3 = random.choice(letter)
    else:
        letter3 = letter_input_3 #allowing user to select a specific letter

    if letter_input_4 == "v":
        letter4 = random.choice(vowels)
    elif letter_input_4 == "c":
        letter4 = random.choice(consonants)
    elif letter_input_4 == "l":
        letter4 = random.choice(letter)
    else:
        letter4 = letter_input_4 #allowing user to select a specific letter

    if letter_input_5 == "v":
        letter5 = random.choice(vowels)
    elif letter_input_5 == "c":
        letter5 = random.choice(consonants)
    elif letter_input_5 == "l":
        letter5 = random.choice(letter)
    else:
        letter5 = letter_input_5 #allowing user to select a specific letter
    name = letter1+letter2+letter3+letter4+letter5
    return(name )

for babynames in range(20):
    print(generator())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a condensed version, that is still easily readable for a beginner:

```
import random, string

def generator(total):
    vowels = 'aeiouy'
    consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
    letter = string.ascii_lowercase

    choices = [""] * total
    for choice in choices:
        choice = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)

    selections = [""] * total
    for x, selection in enumerate(selections):
        selection = input('choose a letter..."v"for vowels, "c" for consonants, "l" for any other letter, or pick any letter: ')

        if selection == "v":
            choices[x] = random.choice(vowels)
        elif selection == "c":
            choices[x] = random.choice(consonants)
        elif selection == "l":
            choices[x] = random.choice(letter)
        else:
            choices[x] = selection #allowing user to select a specific letter

    return("".join(choices))

for babynames in range(20):
    print(generator(5))
```